# Black flicker while resizing translucent Qt widget (only when Aero is enabled)?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, aero, flicker

I have a top-level Qt widget with the FramelessWindowHint flag and the WA_TranslucentBackground attribute set. It has several children, each of which draws an image on it. They are not in a layout. Instead, I simply move them around when something changes (it is not user-resizable).

There are two states to the window - a big state and a small state. When I switch between them, I resize the window and reposition the children. The problem is that as the window resizes, a black box is briefly flashed on the top-level window before the images are painted over it.

The problem goes away if I disable Aero. I found brief mention of this problem being fixed in an article describing a new release of Qt (this release is long past), but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Qt specifically, but I have worked with other windowing toolkits.  Typically you see this kind of flashing when you are drawing updates directly to the screen.  The fix is to instead use [Double buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics), which basically means that you render your updates into an offscreen buffer (a bitmap of some sort,  in the purest sense of the word), and then copy the entire updated image to screen in a single, fast operation.

The reason you only see the flickering sometimes is simply an artifact of how quickly your screen refreshes versus how quickly the updates are drawn.  If you get "lucky" then all the updates occur between screen refreshes and you may not see any flicker.